# Як правильно: кмИн чи кмІн?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники, орфографія

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kmyn) подано тільки статтю про рослину **кмИн**.
Однак натрапила і на іншу Інтернет-статтю [Кмін тміновий (Cuminum cyminum L .)](http://www.food-info.net/ua/products/spices/cumin.htm), в якій вжито термінологію **кмІн**.

Виникає питання: як же правильно вживати це слово?

Comment: Остання стаття має зовсім неправильну назву. Бо [і _кмин_, і _тмин_ означають _Carum carvi L._](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кмин_звичайний), а [_Cuminum cyminum L._ — це _зіра_, або _кумин_, або _римський кмин_](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зіра_(рослина)). (Хоча російською зіру/кумин зрідка називають _«кмин тминовый»_, бо російською якраз [_«тмин»_ — _Carum_](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тмин) і [_«кмин»_ — _Cuminum_](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кмин), але не думаю, що це варто поширювати на українську, де вже склалося, що [і _кмин_, і _тмин_  — _Carum_](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кмин_(рід))).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На позначення цієї рослини в українській мові нормативно вживати 2 слова: [кмин](http://sum.in.ua/s/kmyn) і [тмин](http://sum.in.ua/s/tmyn). Вживання слова **[тмін](http://www.m-translate.com.ua/uk-ru/word-kmin-translation#)** і **[кмін](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/41144/%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD)** (оскільки це діалектизм) в українській мові є ненормативним і виникло це явище, на мою думку, під впливом запозичень:
[image]

[Етимологічний словник](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm).

Comment: Додам, що в тій статті, на які посилаються в запитанні, насправді мова навіть не про _[кмин](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кмин_звичайний)_, а про _[кумин/зіру](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Зіра_(рослина))_ (хоча зрідка «кмином» можуть назвати і _кумин/зіру_, і _[ажгон](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ажгон)_).

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, за [цією](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/4321/585) відповіддю *тмин* та *кмин* унормовані. Про всяк дещо виправлю.

Про [*кмін*](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=472):

> кмин (бот.) «тмин, Carum L.», [*кмен*] Ж, [*кминівка* «горілка на кмині» Ж, [*кминити*] «заправляти кмином» Ж;­ р. болг. [*кмин*], бр. *кмен*, др. *кѷминъ*, п. kmіn, ч. слц. kmin, схв. кмин, слн. kmin;
>
> запозичено з німецької мови (у східнословʼянські мови, можливо, за західнословʼянським посередництвом, зокрема польським); двн. kumīn «кмин» походить від лат. cuminum «тc.», яке зводиться до гр. κύμῑνον «nc.»,
>   очевидно, слова східного походження, пор. гебр. kammōn, аккад. kamūnu
>   «тс.»; можливо, що безпосереднім джерелом словʼянського слова було лат. cumīnum.

З такого погляду важко затверджувати до слова *кмін* московський вплив, цьому також підтверджує [наступне](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD&highlight=on):

> #### Словник українських наукових і народних назв судинних рослин 2004р. (Ю. Кобів)
>
> Carum carvi L.
>
> - кми́н звича́йний (Во, Ру, Оп);
> - кмин (Сл; Рг1, Пс, Жл, Ум, Ів, Гд, Mk, Ос, Ук, Он, Пч, Гб, Коб — загальноукраїнський),
> - кмин польови́й (Вх1, Вх6, Мл),
> - кминок (Вх3; Гв, Вх6, Сл, Mk — подільський),
> - кминок полевий (Вх2);
> - ганус (См — слобожанський),
> - квінок (См),
> - кеминьомг (См),
> - кмен (Жл, Вх6, Mk, Он, Пч — бойківський, закарпатський),
> - кменок (Км),
> - кмень (Mk — покутськобуковинський),
> - кмин городній (Ос — середньонаддніпрянський),
> - кмино (Км),
> - кминянка (Ос — лемківський),
> - кмін (Ан, Hl, Tl, Mj, Rs, Дб, Ів, Сл, Mk, Бк, Гб, Коб — подільський, волинський, покутськобуковинський, гуцульський, лемківський),
> - кмінок (Mk, Ос — волинський, наддністрянський),
> - кмінь (Км),
> - кмон (Ос — волинський),
> - отьмє́н (Лс2 — середньополіський),
> - тимон (Км),
> - тмин (Рг1, Кр, Шм2, Ум, Ів, Сл, Ук — середньонаддніпрянський),
> - тмін (Ан, Rs, Сл, Mk, Лс2, Ос, Коб — середньонаддніпрянський, подільський, волинський, середньополіський, гуцульський),
> - тмін волоський (Tl),
> - томин (См),
> - тьмин (Чн — слобожанський),
> - хмін (Сл),
> - хріновиця (Ан — середньонаддніпрянський),
> - цінці́пер (Гр, Ду),
> - цмин (Ав, Вх1, Ум, Гр, Ду, Ів, Mk, Ук — середньонаддніпрянський),
> - цмін (Mk — середньонаддніпрянський),
> - цьмин (Он — бойківський),
> - чмінь (Сл — східнополіський),
> - чорнушка (Ан — слобожанський).

До прикладу ще [*тмин*](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=585)

> тмин (бот.) «Кмин, Carum L.», [*тмин білий*, *тмин рожевий*] «Котяча
>   лапка дводомна, Antennaria dioica (L.) Gaertn.» Mak, [*тімин*] Пі, [*тмін*] Шейк, [*тмін воложскій*] «Cuminum
>   cyminum L.» Mak, [*тминник*] «маремка підмаренникова, Asperula galioides
>   М.В.», [*тмінник*] Нед, [*отмєн*] ЛЖит, *тминний*;
>
> р. *тмин*, бр. [*тмень*, *цьмен*];
>
> результат видазміни назви кмин.

З такого погляду не можна сказати про вплив чужих мов, окрім впливу очевидного запозичення та поділу (чітко видне між АУ та М імперіями). Наразї це можна назвати діялектізмом, хоча я би так не сказав, скоріш омин унормованости, котре було переважно за совітськи части, через що є підозри, що це *кмин* та *тмин* є омосковченням (звучня ріжна, але пишуться однаково, відносно відома практика: один з прикладів підтримки совітами «винятку 9»; мета виконана: словники не мають *кмін* чи *тмін*, навіть з позначкою *діялект*).

Тому, коли не зважати на сучасні унормованости, що є важливим в офіційному і в подібному стилі, то в вільному стилі можна вживати те, що до смаку.